# Regex to detect if variables or other functions are used in function parameter

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a console application to scan classic asp pages and do a match on the asp function getcontentdirect("") The code at the bottom is an example of some random snippets of code that I am scanning.

I'm using the following regex - `(?<=getContentDirect)([(][^)]*)[)]`.

I need 2 regex's to find the functions that

a - Finds just  : ("Content User") so no ampersands or commas. (the word Content User is a word to be searched in the database and could be anyword)

b - Finds anything that is not that as above so `("OLCINTRO " & obj_Session.GetDetail("CurrentCurriculumID", "0") & "/" & str_Action)`

I need to be able to check if the function contains variables or other functions. My above regex finds both.

I'm using http://regexhero.net/tester/ to test my regex.

```
00165: Response.Write "<div style=""margin-left:2.5%""><span class=""Content1"">" & obj_Content.getContentDirect("Content User") & _
00247: <td><%=obj_Content.GetContentDirect("OLCINTRO " & obj_Session.GetDetail("CurrentCurriculumID", "0") & "/" & str_Action)%></td>
<td><%=obj_Content.GetContentDirect("OLCINTRO " & obj_Session.GetDetail("CurrentCurriculumID", "0") & "/" & str_Action)%></td>
if len(LgSelect(25))=0 then LgSelect(25)= obj_Content.getContentDirect("CONTENT SelectRatee")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to detect that in a single regex, but it's possible to process the string in stages something like this:

Capture up to one level of nested parentheses in group 1:

```
(?<=(?i)getContentDirect)\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\)
```

Remove any string literals:

```
"[^"]*"
```

Search for a letter which is part of a variable or function name:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Is this what you meant?

   ```
   var re = new Regex(@"getContentDirect\( *\"Content User\" *\)");
   ```
2. Since you're using C# and .NET you can take advantage of its [`balancing groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).

   ```
   var re = new Regex(@"getContentDirect\((
       (?:               
       [^()]             # Match non-brackets
       |
       (?<BR> \( )       # Match '(', and capture into 'BR'
       |
       (?<-BR> \) )      # Match ')', and delete the 'BR' capture
       )+
       (?(BR)(?!))       # Fails if 'BR' stack isn't empty!
   )\)"; RegexOptions.IgnoreWhitespace);
   ```

This captures the insides in `\1`. It basically goes through the contents (`...`) of the `getContentDirect(...)`, and if it encounters a non-bracket it captures it, if it encounters an opening bracket it takes note of it and increases the `BR` counter (think of it as a count of how many opening brackets we've found), and if it encounters a closing bracket, it decreases the `BR` counter.

The `(?(BR)(?!)` says "don't match unless the the `BR` counter is 0", i.e. the number of opening brackets we've seen equals the number of closing brackets.